# iOS app text looks bigger is Fixed by using launch screen

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift2, swift3

I developed a project one year ago in `swift 2.0` , recently i updated it to `swift 3.0` . Today i run that app into my iPhone 6 , all text looks so big. Including status bar. I thought it is a issue with current project

So i tried to download my app from `iOS appstore` which was uploaded using `Xcode 7` , the app text looks so big

Is the above one is the issue with my phone or it is a generic issue `Xcode 8`.

But when i develop a sample project using `Xcode 8` , the all text looks normal in size.

**Update**: I used Image set for splash image so i changed it to launch screen now text look Normal

Comment: Add some images or reference links.

Comment: It's possible the default font the app uses is different; in older Xcode and iOS the default was Helvetica Neue, in the more most recent it's San Francisco.

Comment: How to change that app looks ugly in ios 10 ?

Comment: probably you did not support iPhone6/7 or iPhone 6+/7+ screen sizes and the iPhone5/SE screens are upscaled only.

Comment: i have updated my  question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Already faced same issue...

You have problem with your splash screen.

Do as follow, it will help you.

1 ) Remove your splash screen from Project.

2 ) Add splash screen using `Images.xcassets`

3 ) Do following setting if require.

```
Go to -> Project setting - > app icon and launch image -> In source set it to you asset file and also name below
```

So, I am sorry to say this is not an issue of XCode 8.0 or Swift 3.0

**Note: Your problem is in your project you have not include splash screen for iPhone 6. You can directly add the splash screen for iPhone 6**

Comment: Thanks @Hitesh surani it fixed my issue , i replaced launch screen instead of my image asset which fixed my issue